# How to start RecentApplicationsDialog?

Tags: java, android

When I press and hold the home button, the RecentApplicationsDialog is shown. How can I do this in code?

Comment: May be this http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=622666 can help you....

Answer (score 0):

The class is public:

```
public class RecentApplicationsDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
```

Its the package:
    com.android.internal.policy.impl.RecentApplicationsDialog

Have you tried [creating the dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)?